# npm, node error how can i solve them

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

i am new to node.js.
this is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "chat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "chat ap by umer",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.10.2",
        "socket.io": "^1.3.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": { },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "/path/to/origin.git"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

and on heroku server i got these error logs.
i am getting these errors on npm git. can anyone solve this.

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@2.11.3
>
> 3 info using node@v0.12.7
>
> 4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
>
> 4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:142:19)
>
> 4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:58:5
>
> 4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:345:5
>
> 4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:309:45)
>
> 4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:343:3)
>
> 4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:113:5)
>
> 4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:300:12
>
> 4 verbose stack     at evalmachine.:334:14
>
> 4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:102:5
>
> 4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.:95:15)
>
> 5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Umer MehAr\Desktop\pro
>
> 6 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> 7 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>
> 8 error node v0.12.7
>
> 9 error npm  v2.11.3
>
> 10 error missing script: start
>
> 11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
>
> 11 error     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> 12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 1):

The error is clearly stated **Error: missing script: start**.

The `scripts` of your package.json needs to have a start value. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Comment: can u explain a lil bit more.. do i have to edit my package.json? do i add this script object at the start of my .json or i have to create a new json through npm init? if yes than i dont think so  there is any script value taken by us..

Comment: You have to edit the existing package.json and there is a already a `scripts` value, it's in the json you put in your question. You just have to add `start` in this part. More information on package.json here: http://browsenpm.org/package.json